# MySQL query to find free timegaps between events

Tags: mysql

I'm working on an appointment system developed in PHP and MySQL. I'm currently having problems with getting my free time query to work.

I have two tables:

```
-- Table: works
CREATE TABLE works (
    id int  NOT NULL,
    department_id int  NOT NULL,
    worker_id int  NOT NULL,
    worker_type int  NOT NULL,
    time_start datetime  NOT NULL,
    time_end datetime  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT works_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- Table: free_times
CREATE TABLE free_times (
    id int  NOT NULL,
    department_id int  NOT NULL,
    worker_id int  NOT NULL,
    worker_type int  NOT NULL,
    start_dt datetime  NOT NULL,
    end_dt datetime  NOT NULL,
    duration int  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT free_times_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I need a query to get free time spans between works in table `works` and store them in table `free_times`. The time span should be in minutes.

The query that I'm using right now looks like this:

```
SELECT e1.department_id, e1.worker_type, e1.worker_id,
e1.time_end as free_time_start,
e2.time_start as free_time_end,
MIN(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, e1.time_end, e2.time_start)) as duration
FROM works e1
JOIN works e2
ON e1.department_id=e2.department_id
AND e1.worker_type=e2.worker_type
AND e1.worker_id=e2.worker_id
AND e1.time_end <= e2.time_start
WHERE e1.department_id=? AND e1.worker_id=? AND e1.worker_type=?
AND ((e1.time_end >= '2018-09-06 08:00:00' AND e2.time_start <= '2018-09-06 17:00:00'))
GROUP BY e1.worker_id, e2.time_end
```

Now, to get this query to work, i need to insert dummy works into the `works` table prior running the query. These dummy works act like limiters for the day. I add one work to the beginning of the workday with `time_start` and `time_end` `2018-09-06 08:00` and one work to the end of the workday with `time_start` and `time_end` `2018-09-06 17:00`

Let's try it with this dummy data (day delimitters added):

```
INSERT INTO `works` (`id`, `department_id`, `worker_id`, `worker_type`, `time_start`, `time_end`) VALUES
(1, 1, 15, 1, '2018-09-06 08:00:00', '2018-09-06 08:00:00'),
(2, 1, 15, 1, '2018-09-06 09:30:00', '2018-09-06 10:30:00'),
(4, 1, 15, 1, '2018-09-06 11:00:00', '2018-09-06 13:00:00'),
(3, 1, 15, 1, '2018-09-06 17:00:00', '2018-09-06 17:00:00');
```

Running the free time query gives me result:

"free_time_start":"**2018-09-06 08:00:00**","free_time_end":"**2018-09-06 08:00:00**","duration":"0"
"free_time_start":"**2018-09-06 08:00:00**","free_time_end":"**2018-09-06 09:30:00**","duration":"90"
"free_time_start":"**2018-09-06 10:30:00**","free_time_end":"**2018-09-06 11:00:00**","duration":"30"
"free_time_start":"**2018-09-06 17:00:00**","free_time_end":"**2018-09-06 17:00:00**","duration":"0"

Somehow I am missing a time span from **13:00** to **17:00** and I really can't figure it out by myself. Any advice to get this query working is welcome.

All I need is to get the query to find free time spans working, storing the result and inserting and removing the day start and end delimiters is already handled.

Edit: MySql version is 5.1.72

Comment: Which version of MySQL or MariaDB do you use? It makes a difference because recent versions have better support for the kind of query you want (window functions). Please [edit] your question. By the way, this task is not simple to do in SQL. Your application might be more maintainable if you used php.

Comment: @O.Jones Edited, it's version is 5.1.72, so it's kinda old.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get both start end end time for both e1 and e2, and only join when e2.time_end is different to e1.time_start as:

```
SELECT e1.department_id, e1.worker_type, e1.worker_id,
e1.time_start as work1_start,
e1.time_end as work1_end,
e2.time_start as work2_start,
e2.time_end as work2_end,
MIN(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, e1.time_end, e2.time_start)) as duration
FROM works e1
JOIN works e2
ON e1.department_id=e2.department_id
AND e1.time_end <= e2.time_start
AND e2.time_end <> e1.time_start
WHERE e1.department_id=1 AND e1.worker_id=15 AND e1.worker_type=1
AND ((e1.time_end >= '2018-09-06 08:00:00' AND e2.time_start <= '2018-09-06 17:00:00'))
GROUP BY e1.worker_id, e1.time_start
```

Output:

```
work1_start             work1_end               work2_start             work2_end               duration
2018-09-06 08:00:00     2018-09-06 08:00:00     2018-09-06 09:30:00     2018-09-06 10:30:00     90
2018-09-06 09:30:00     2018-09-06 10:30:00     2018-09-06 17:00:00     2018-09-06 17:00:00     30
2018-09-06 11:00:00     2018-09-06 13:00:00     2018-09-06 17:00:00     2018-09-06 17:00:00     240
```

---

Update:

Added the new row `INSERT INTO`works`(`id`,`department_id`,`worker_id`,`worker_type`,`time_start`,`time_end`) VALUES
(5, 1, 15, 1, '2018-09-06 14:00:00', '2018-09-06 15:00:00');`

Reorder ID's as:

```
1   1   15  1   2018-09-06 08:00:00 2018-09-06 08:00:00
2   1   15  1   2018-09-06 09:30:00 2018-09-06 10:30:00
3   1   15  1   2018-09-06 11:00:00 2018-09-06 13:00:00
4   1   15  1   2018-09-06 14:00:00 2018-09-06 15:00:00
5   1   15  1   2018-09-06 17:00:00 2018-09-06 17:00:00
```

Rerun the query:

```
work1_start             work1_end               work2_start             work2_end               duration
2018-09-06 08:00:00     2018-09-06 08:00:00     2018-09-06 09:30:00     2018-09-06 10:30:00     90
2018-09-06 09:30:00     2018-09-06 10:30:00     2018-09-06 11:00:00     2018-09-06 13:00:00     30
2018-09-06 11:00:00     2018-09-06 13:00:00     2018-09-06 14:00:00     2018-09-06 15:00:00     60
2018-09-06 14:00:00     2018-09-06 15:00:00     2018-09-06 17:00:00     2018-09-06 17:00:00     120
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but when i add third work with duration 14:00 - 15:00 I will get additional rows:
["work1_end"]=>string(19) "2018-09-06 13:00:00" ["work2_start"]=> string(19) "2018-09-06 17:00:00" ["duration"]=> string(2) "60"  

and

["work1_end"]=> string(19) "2018-09-06 15:00:00" ["work2_start"]=> string(19) "2018-09-06 17:00:00" ["duration"]=> string(3) "120"

Comment: Updated answer.